# Run Zxing first time shows camera with white background

Tags: android

I have Integrated ZXing code into my own app and I have commented the code to show help screen on first launch.

I have commeneted the method "showHelpOnFirstLaunch()" method and try to run it, It shows like the following:

[image]

But from the secong time It works great...I dont know how to solve this.. Can anyone pls help??

Comment: You are running in Real Device or Emulator?

Comment: in real device only ..From the second time It works well..But here the first time It shows mw like this

Comment: PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true); add this line before your showHelpOnFirstLaunch() method

Comment: No, It still showing the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

It was just because of background color: In captureActivity, onResume() method -> where ViewFinderView id initialised, I have just set the color of viewFinderView as:

```
  ViewFinderView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Thats all..And now Its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside showHelpOnFirstLaunch() you will be having below snippet :

```
if (currentVersion > lastVersion) {
            prefs.edit()
                    .putInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN,
                            currentVersion).commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            String page = lastVersion == 0 ? HelpActivity.DEFAULT_PAGE
                    : HelpActivity.WHATS_NEW_PAGE;
            intent.putExtra(HelpActivity.REQUESTED_PAGE_KEY, page);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
}
```

Just comment this code inside showHelpOnFirstLaunch(); Also call showHelpOnFirstLaunch() method

Comment: Now again, It is showing me the same view, but throws an exception from showHelpOnFirstLaunch() :  android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android
06-25 13:35:38.169: W/CaptureActivity(31692):  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ContextImpl.java:1734)
06-25 13:35:38.169: W/CaptureActivity(31692):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.showHelpOnFirstLaunch(CaptureActivity.java:690)